# Server headers - 302 temporary redirect

Tags: linux, apache, http-headers

I have just checked the server headers for my website and this is what i got:

```
1 Server Response: http://www.pjnsports.co.uk
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Length: 0
Location: /?6690d3e0
```

I havent set up any 302 redirects - i assume this will be my host that is doing this. Is this normal practice?? will it have a negative affect on search results, site load speed etc? basically should i be going to them and telling them to do something about it?

Cheers

Paul

Comment: Who is 'Them'? And are you using any server-side technology? As the server-side framework might be adding that in the case that the user has the cookies disabled to track the session

Comment: them is my host. By server side tech what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting any 302 / 301 going to that site:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.pjnsports.co.uk
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/9.0.597.107 Safari/534.13
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: PHPSESSID=emr10g0gs9srtjccadb4k7t846; language=en; currency=GBP; __utmz=239376578.1300041169.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=239376578.1365490247.1300041169.1300041169.1300041169.1; __utmc=239376578; __utmb=239376578.1.10.1300041169

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 13 Mar 2011 18:33:41 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 6531
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: what site are u using to get that data?